# multiple useEffect in a component doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks, use-effect

When I call API from single `useEffect`, it works perfectly. But when I am trying to call another API from another `useEffect` in the same component its shows a [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RaV4.png).

If it's possible, please have a look at my project on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-ives-mqmz1?file=/src/components/Dashboard/Dashboard.js).

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';

const TeacherDashboard = () => {
    // console.log(props)
    const [appointmentList, setAppointmentList] = useState([]);
    const [viewProfile, setViewProfile] = useState([]);
    console.log(viewProfile);
    useEffect(() => {
        async function loadData(){
            const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4200/appointments')
                const data = await response.json();
                setAppointmentList(data)
        }
        loadData()
    }, [appointmentList])

    useEffect(() => {
        async function proData() {
            const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4200/schedule')
            const data = await response.json();
            setViewProfile(data)
        }
        proData()
    }, [viewProfile])

    return (
        <Container>
            <Row>
                <Col>
                   {
                       appointmentList.map(app => 
                           <div style={{border: '1px solid blue'}}>
                               <li>Name : {app.name} </li>
                               <li>Id : {app.s_id} </li>
                               <li>Sec : {app.sec} </li>
                               <li>Email : {app.email} </li>
                               <li>Date & Time : {app.dateTime} </li>
                           </div>

                        )
                   }
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </Container>
    );
};

export default TeacherDashboard;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure the purpose of setting both `appointmentList` and `viewProfile` states as the part of the dependency arrays of both `useEffect` hooks. Both of them will eventually result in an infinite loop as you are directly updating the respective states in the `useEffect` hooks.

From what I can see, you only need to make both requests once, thus you should be using an empty array as the dependency array, such that both requests will be called only when the component is mounted. This is how it can be done:

```
useEffect(() => {
  async function proData() {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4200/schedule')
    const data = await response.json();
    setViewProfile(data)
  }
  proData();
  async function loadData(){
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4200/appointments')
    const data = await response.json();
    setAppointmentList(data)
  }
  loadData();
}, []);
```

Comment: Thank You. I just pass [appointmentList, viewProfile]. then its work

useEffect(() => {
        async function proData() {
            const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4200/profiles')
            const data = await response.json();
            setViewProfile(data)
        }
        proData();
        async function loadData() {
            const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4200/appointments')
            const data = await response.json();
            setAppointmentList(data)
        }
        loadData();
    }, [appointmentList, viewProfile]);

Comment: Ahh I see..! Yea that works too! Good job on figuring that out